# Pyramid force download generated file

Tags: download, pyramid

I need to export GPX file from pyramid application. I've prepared gpx template in jinja2 and it works fine, but now, I want to offer to user download, instead of displaying file in browser.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution:

```
response = render_to_response( <template>, <data>, request=request)
response.content_type = 'application/gpx+xml'
response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="file.gpx"'
return response
```